# Cannot add custom image uploader for custome post type in custom wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I am trying to set image uploader for a custom post type on a Theme I am developing.

The aim is to get it to insert the image URL into the textbox of id "meta-image" but instead it inserts the image into the content editor field!

here is the code I have so far: this displays the button and text input:

```
<?php 
        global $post;
        $prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );   
?>
<p>
            <label for="meta-image" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Service Icon', 'prfx-textdomain' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="meta-image" id="meta-image" value="<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-image'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['meta-image'][0]; ?>" />
            <input type="button" id="meta-image-button" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Choose or Upload an Image', 'prfx-textdomain' ); ?>" />
</p>
```

this includes the necessary js for admin area:

```
    /**
 * Loads the image management javascript
 */
function prfx_image_enqueue() {
    global $typenow;
    if( $typenow == 'service' ) {
        wp_enqueue_media();

        // Registers and enqueues the required javascript.
        wp_register_script( 'meta-box-image', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/meta-box-image.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'meta-box-image', 'meta_image',
            array(
                'title' => __( 'Choose or Upload an Image', 'prfx-textdomain' ),
                'button' => __( 'Use this image', 'prfx-textdomain' ),
            )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-box-image' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'prfx_image_enqueue' );
```

and this is the js:

```
/*
 * Attaches the image uploader to the input field
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
    var meta_image_frame;

    // Runs when the image button is clicked.
    jQuery('#meta-image-button').click(function(e){

        // Prevents the default action from occuring.
        e.preventDefault();

        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if ( meta_image_frame ) {
            wp.media.editor.open();
            return;
        }

        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
            title: meta_image.title,
            button: { text:  meta_image.button },
            library: { type: 'image' }
        });

        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){

            // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
            var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
            jQuery('#meta-image').val(media_attachment.url);
        });

        // Opens the media library frame.
        wp.media.editor.open();
    });
});
```

any ideas on how to get this actually storing to the proper area?

Comment: It might be easier using ACF for this. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ The free version has image support.

Comment: @Aibrean yes ACF is perfect however I really want this theme from scratch. So that when a user installs it, it all just appears